# No token being sent with request

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I have a Vuex action that gets run each time a page loads (not router.push), this function seems to run fine in the sense that it checks for a token and if the token exists it moves on. My issue is that I am dispatching another action which requires this token.

Okay so a bit clearer, I am using Axios with Vue.js to send API request. I have the authorization header set to a Vuex store value in my main.js file. I then have my App.uve load which triggers a default action to run which checks for the existance of a token (JWT). This default action also dispatches another action called `storeUser` which sends off a GET request to a user info API endpoint. When sending this user info API call I am seeing on my back end that it is not an authorized API call. Checking into the headers I need the authorization header is `undefined`. Below is what I believe to be the relavent code.

**Default action that runs on App.vue load**

```
tryAutoLogin({commit, dispatch}) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  if(!token) {return}
    commit('authUser',{
    token
  })
  dispatch('storeUser')
},
```

**second action that is causing the issue**

```
storeUser({commit, state}, userData) {
  if(!state.token) return
  axios.get('/user/userInfo')
   .then(res => {
     console.log(res)
  })
   .catch(err => {
     console.log(err)
  })
},
```

**main.js needed parts**

```
import store from './store/store.js'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = store.token
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  store,
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

I cut out a ton in main.js to make it cleaner but those are the related parts to this issue. I don't think that there is anything else.

**store.js state**

```
state: {
  token: null,
  name: '',
  companyName: ''
},
```

Comment: `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = store.token`  this only happens once, before your token is set. Use an interceptor instead to add the token to requests at call time

Comment: Also, it should be `store.state.token`

Comment: @Phil Thank you the interceptor method worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Phil in the comments on the OP I have the below code working.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  config.headers.Authorization = store.state.token;
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```